# Child component is not rendering passed parent value through @Input

Tags: angular, typescript, tailwind-css

```
// PARENT app.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Profile } from './entity/Profile';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'personal-finance-client';
  profile : Profile = new Profile();

}
```

```
// PARENT app.component.html

<app-navbar *ngIf="profile" [profile]="profile" [title]="title" />
<div class="font-bold text-3xl">
  {{title}}
  {{profile.getName()}}
</div>
```

```
// CHILD navbar.component.html

<p>{{myTitle}}</p>
```

```
// CHILD navbar.component.ts

import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Profile } from '../entity/Profile';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit{
  private _title? : string;

  @Input()
  set title(value: string | undefined){
    this._title = value;
    if(value){
      this.myTitle = value;
    }

  }

  get title() {
    return this._title;
  }

  @Input() profile!: Profile;

  profileName: string = this.profile?.getName();
  myTitle!: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
      alert(this.profile?.getName())
  }
}
```

I couldn't get myTitle in CHILD navbar.component.html file rendered with parent title that is supposedly to be 'personal-finance-client'. I had tried debugging the value with console.log inside OnInit of navbar.component.ts, it printed undefined at first, then the actual value of 'personal-finance-client'.

It seems like the child component is only taking the first OnInit value and not rendered when a new value seems to appear?

Is this a normal behavior because I can't seem to successfully pass parent value to the child value in this case.

I have tried employing ngOnChanges and pass the change value to the new field, but no value is rendered to the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the probable cause, I had initialized the app with sass then had to change back to css but doing it manually. This may cause the rendering error and probably has something to do with sass.

After recreating a clean angular project that I can see the parent value is rendered from child component.